# Can we get Notifications or Push Messages from YouTube Channel on Android App?

Tags: android, youtube, push-notification

My Android app is successfully fetching data from my YouTube channel using YouTube data API for example Playlists, Thumbnails, views etc. Now i want to add one more functionality in the App and that is

**This is what i want to do**

> Whenever i do any changes on my YouTube Channel for example :
>
> - Uploading New Video
> - Creating New Playlist
> - Updating any title or description etc
>
> then i want to send a **Notification** or a **Push Message** to my App user to
>   tell him/her that check out what we uploaded new on our channel

So, please can someone tell me **is it possible somehow or not ?**
if yes then how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can subscribe to push notifications on updates on any channel, then use your own backend to handle the notifications and send your own notifications to your app.

Refer to this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications